# How to get list of chktex warnings?

Tags: auctex

I am using emacs with auctex and chktex lint. How do I display a list of warning that chktex detects in my document? Or how do I go to the next warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested `chktex` with

- emacs-version 25.1.50.2, started with `emacs -Q` and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-initialize`.
- auctex-11.90.2 (installed via `package-install`).

The command `ChkTeX` is already a member of `TeX-command-list`.

- Open your LaTeX document
- press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> type `ChkTeX` (use <kbd>TAB</kbd>-completion), and press <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

You are presented with a compilation buffer. There the error messages/warnings of `chktex` are listed. Each of the entries of this list has a link to the position of the problem in the LaTeX file.

[image: Compilation buffer opened by ChkTeX]

You can go to the next error/warning with the key sequence <kbd>C-c `</kbd>.